# Find first json object with given key name recursively using jq

Tags: json, limit, jq

How can I find recursively first key with given name using jq?

Suppose I have JSON structure:

```
{
  "firstKey": { 
      "secondKey": {
          "model": {
              "name": {
                  ....
               } 
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any way how to tell jq to return me first found json object with key name for example in this case "model"? So it returns:

```
"model": {
    "name:" {
      ....
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select just the first, use `first`:

```
first(.. | objects | select(has("model")))
```

or if minimizing keystrokes is a goal:

```
first(..|select(.model?))
```

Or, if your input has more than one top-level JSON document, and you only want at most one from the bunch:

```
jq -n 'first(inputs|..|select(.model?))'
```